# Error trying to compile Raspberry Pi 3.10 kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

Helo, I am trying to compile the Raspberry Pi's linux 3.10 kernel following the instructions from [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation#Perform_the_compilation). I have got the kernel from https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux and I am using [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi) compiler.

Everything goes well until I have to run

> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}

This is the output with the errors I get:

```
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' está actualizado.
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
  GEN     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  GZIP    kernel/config_data.gz
  CHK     kernel/config_data.h
  CC [M]  drivers/net/wireless/rtl8192cu/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from drivers/net/wireless/rtl8192cu/include/osdep_service.h:1233:0,
             from drivers/net/wireless/rtl8192cu/core/rtw_cmd.c:23:
drivers/net/wireless/rtl8192cu/include/rtw_byteorder.h:36:2: error: #error "Must be LITTLE/BIG Endian Host"
In file included from drivers/net/wireless/rtl8192cu/include/drv_types.h:83:0,
             from drivers/net/wireless/rtl8192cu/core/rtw_cmd.c:24:
drivers/net/wireless/rtl8192cu/include/rtw_mlme_ext.h:886:2: error: #error "Must be LITTLE or BIG Endian"
make[4]: *** [drivers/net/wireless/rtl8192cu/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [drivers/net/wireless/rtl8192cu] Error 2
make[2]: *** [drivers/net/wireless] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers/net] Error 2
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

How can I solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been digging around Google for weeks to solve the exact problem that you faced.

Not that I've got the direct answer, but at least by following the exact steps shown in the link below, I've been able to compiled an image that is able to boot up Raspbian (with errors left to be solved, still) on the RPI.

http://helloraspberrypi.blogspot.tw/2014/01/cross-compile-raspberry-pi-kernel-from.html

The steps are as follows:

Create our working directory, raspberrypi:

> $ mkdir raspberrypi
>   $ cd raspberrypi

Before start our works, install the necessary tools and source code of Raspberry Pi linux:

> $ git clone https: //github.com/raspberrypi/tools.git
>   $ git clone https: //github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git

Prepare the .config file from pre-packaged config, bcmrpi_cutdown_defconfig:

> $ cd linux
>   $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- bcmrpi_cutdown_defconfig

========== **Take Note** ==========

For the sake of readability, I won't be including the details of how I solve my problem with mouse and keyboard not working after the "startx" command.

However,

> $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- menuconfig

was used rather than

> $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- bcmrpi_cutdown_defconfig

I can provide more details if required.

========== **Take Note** ==========

Build kernel:

> $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-
>   $ mkdir ../modules
>   $ make modules_install ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=../modules/
>   $ cd ../tools/mkimage/
>   $ ./imagetool-uncompressed.py ../../linux/arch/arm/boot/Image

Now insert a Raspbian installed SD Card, and run the command:

> $ sudo rm /media//kernel.img
>   $ sudo mv kernel.img /media//
>   $ sudo rm -rf /media//lib/modules/
>   $ sudo rm -rf /media//lib/firmware/
>   $ cd ../../modules/
>   $ sudo cp -a lib/modules/ /media//lib/
>   $ sudo cp -a lib/firmware/ /media//lib/
>   $ sync

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. When providing an answer on this site it is preferred that all the relevant points are posted in the actual answer and not linked to. By all means provide the link as additional material.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Deepend, Barranka: I edited the answers and added all the necessary steps to compile a workable image.

Comment: @Saksham: I know that I didn't answer how to solve the driver errors as I couldn't solve it as well. However, the main goal of Bouchard and me is the same, we want a self-compiled, workable image and the steps that I provided serves this purpose without having to go through solving the driver errors. Hopefully this answer is able to help those who were just as lost as I were out there.